# Redux is not dispatching my action type in a functional Component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create a Login page from scratch using redux, but since I converted my component to a functional one, my payload is not being dispatched. I debugged my backend and it's working fine, my response is sending me the JWT. The only problem is the payload.
This is my component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signIn } from '../ducks/actions/adminActions'

const Login = (state: any) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const onEmailChange = (event: any) => {
        setEmail(event.target.value)
    };
    const onPasswordChange = (event: any) => {
        setPassword(event.target.value)
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <h4>Email</h4>
            <input type="text" onChange={onEmailChange}/>
            <h4>Password</h4>
            <input type="text" onChange={onPasswordChange}/>

            <button type="submit" onClick={signIn({email, password})}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
    return {
        isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn
    };
};
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { signIn }
)(Login);
```

This is my action:

```
import {
  SIGN_IN,
  SIGN_UP
} from "../types";

export const signIn = ({ email, password }: {email: string, password: string,}) => async (dispatch: any) => {
  try {
    const response = await AlleSys.post('/users/login', {email, password});
    dispatch({type: 'SIGN_IN', payload: response.data});
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('ALLESYS - ERROR: Couldnt establish connection with database');
  }
};
```

And this is my reducer:

```
import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_UP } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  isSignedIn: null,
  userId: null
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SIGN_IN':
      return {...state, isSignedIn: true, userId: action.payload};
```

What I know, is that the action is being called and receiving the response, but it's not dispatching the payload. This code worked fine with a class based component. Looking to my redux debugger, I see that no reducer is called. I guess that I'm messing with something in mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix.

```
const Login = (state: any) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const onEmailChange = (event: any) => {
        setEmail(event.target.value)
    };

    const onPasswordChange = (event: any) => {
        setPassword(event.target.value)
    };

    const send = ({email, password} : {email:  string, password: string}) => {
        state.signIn({email, password});
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h4>Email</h4>
            <input type="text" onChange={onEmailChange}/>
            <h4>Password</h4>
            <input type="text" onChange={onPasswordChange}/>

            <button type="submit" onClick={() => send({email, password})}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
    return {
        isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { signIn }
)(Login);
```